# Error Retrieving Large Report from SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, reporting-services

I've got an SSRS report that I am trying to load into a ReportViewer control via a .NET webservice, like so:

```
    // CR8720 DT 10/20/10 10 VVVIMP: The report is dynmically created w/o using the RDL file.
    MemoryStream ms = HtmlStatement.GetReport(uxStatementText.Text, uxStatementName.Text, uxStatementCode.Text);
    uxReportViewer.ServerReport.LoadReportDefinition(ms);
```

This report can be filtered using search criteria on my ASP.NET page, or the criteria can be left blank and an entire report can be returned. The problem is, when the search criteria is left blank, I get this error message, and no report is returned: "The report definition is not valid.  Details: The element 'Paragraphs' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'Paragraph' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'. (rsInvalidReportDefinition)". The report works fine if I filter it, so I'm thinking that it just may be too large for the webservice to return, and part of it is getting truncated (hence the error message). Is that correct? If so, how would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing the `httpRuntime` and [Report Execution Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181194.aspx):

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout = "10800" />
</system.web>
```

**Ref:**

[Manage timeouts in the Reporting Services 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859693/manage-timeouts-in-the-reporting-services-2005)

Comment: I do believe you are correct, in one way or another...one my my users finally got a more informative error message: Message : The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:10:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. Thanks!