# Reporting Services Timeouts and Display Issues

Tags: ssrs-2008

Reports that are being delivered via email/fileshare from SSRS work fine but when I try to run those same reports from IE at the management portal (http://reportserver/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx) it doesn't respond properly. At times the browser times out when connecting a report link and doesn't even display the report viewer. Other times the report viewer is displayed but the report isn't rendered. This seems to happen more on reports with larger data sets so I believe it's a timeout issue but I've tried changing what settings I can find and nothing has worked yet. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows 7 machine. I tried the suggestions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859693/manage-timeouts-in-the-reporting-services-2005) and still have issues with the viewer not rendering the report when it's a larger data set.

Comment: try running fiddler and check the response you get. Is it really the timeout or is it something to do with your browser settings..or may be its worth to check on your colleague's machine who uses different version of browser may be.

Comment: I don't think it's a browser setting. If I hit refresh enough times it usually displays the report because I think it's caching the query results on the back end and the query isn't taking as long with each refresh. Once it gets below the 10-15 second mark for the query to finish it seems that the renderer takes over and displays the report. I'm not sure what you mean by "running fiddler".