# SSRS Session Cookies Report Viewer control

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I'm using .NET Report Viewer to run SSRS reports. One thing I noticed is that every time I load a page (not postback) it adds a new session cookie. However after awhile Report Viewer fails due to too big request (too many cookies). Is there any way to delete these cookies? I tried to delete Http Sessions on page load, but cookies are not removed.

I can stop creating new cookies by setting on report viewer control `KeepSessionAlive="false"`, but all old cookies stays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you review these three links i provide below, they might turn out to be of great help

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emilianb/archive/2009/05/28/timeouts-and-microsoft-sql-server-2005-reporting-services.aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dynamicsaxbi/archive/2013/02/14/how-to-addressing-ssrs-session-timeouts.aspx
3. [Manage timeouts in the Reporting Services 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859693/manage-timeouts-in-the-reporting-services-2005)

Comment: Hi, this doesn't fixed my issue with cookies, but I can use now `KeepSessionAlive="false"` These articles put me on correct track.